# Controlling video player from CQ5

Tags: aem

Im new to cq5 and am looking to work with videos in it.  What I'd like to do is have several available thumbnails that a user can click on and load the appropriate video into the player.  The player I'd like to use is either the video player from the video component that comes with cq5 or the strobe media playback player that patrick Heinzelmann got working in cq5.  Can someone please explain how i could do this, if there are any examples out there that would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: If all else fails, Adobe is pushing Scene7 for its media. Might be a viable option if you are not able to get the results you want.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [videojs](http://videojs.com/) and the new scene7 player in 5.6.

The general setup would be to:

Install [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) or Scene7 on the server to create the needed video renditions and thumbnails automatically.

Make a custom component that would allow the author to select multiple videos in the dam or on Scene7 and display the automatically processed thumbnails into a nice front facing list with a master player div that is loaded with a placeholder or the first video in the list.

When one of the video thumbnails are selected, dynamically inject the video player code into your main playing div.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some clues on how to achieve this in the SMP documentation -

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/osmf.adobe/index.php?title=Features

specifically, you might be able to control this using the JavaScript features:

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/osmf.adobe/index.php?title=HTML5_%26_JavaScript_support_for_SMP

Hope this helps,
Antony

Answer (score 0):

Refer these URl and they are self explanatory :

[Video Components](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/wcm/default_components/VideoComponents.html)

[Video/Media Converter](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/dam/dam_media_handlers.html)

In Adobe CQ5, we have to use ffmpef coded .ogv format video and for linking to youtube rendered video, we just need to implement ffmpeg in the path